# (Dialect) What does て言うといた mean?

Tags: reading-comprehension, dialects

[image]

In this page, the character says basically "I never saw a cool kid like you. So I was pretty excited/enthusiast"

Then in the next page, he adds this:

[image]

I'm sorta stumbled on what he's trying to say here. Maybe it's because of the kansai but from context I can guess he's saying "the content of what you way is super interesting"? However it doesn't feel like  grammar wise.

Comment: Perhaps there's slight misinterpretation in the first picture? In the first picture, the character says something like "She (or he?) was so excited, saying she'd never seen a cool kid like that".   In the second: "(So) I told (her) that he was super funny inside". The character and the person who was excited are two different persons, and the character is most likely speaking to the "cool" guy.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thank you. It seems my reading of the first sentence was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

言うといた means 言っておいた.

The speaker told whoever was saying あんなかっこいい子見たことない that the listener (or whoever is かっこいい) is super funny inside.